# Better way to change specific chars in a string separated by underscores without using re

Tags: python, list, split

I have files with names like `centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21_2.0.jpg`. I want to change the last string i.e. `image_name.split('_')[5].split('.')[0]` to some other string. I can't seem to find a neat way to do this and ended up doing the following which is very crude

```
 new_name = image_base.split('_')[0] + image_base.split('_')[1] + image_base.split('_')[2] + image_base.split('_')[3] + image_base.split('_')[4] + frameNumber
```

That is, my output should be `centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21_<some string>.0.jpg`
Any better way is appreciated. Note: I want to retain the rest of the string too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you may be looking for this:

```
>>> "centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21_2.0.jpg".rpartition("_")
('centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21', '_', '2.0.jpg')
```

That is for the last element. But from the comments I gather you want to split at delimiter *n*.

```
>>> n = 3
>>> temp = "centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21_2.0.jpg".split("_",n)
>>> "_".join(temp[:n]),temp[n]
('centerOne_camera_2', '2018-04-11_15:11:21_2.0.jpg')
```

I'm not sure what your objection to using `+` is, but you can do this if you like:

```
>>> temp="centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21_2.0.jpg".rpartition("_")
>>> "{0}<some_string>{2}".format(*temp)
'centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21<some_string>2.0.jpg'
```

Comment: this works for me now. Thanks! However, I'd like to know if there is another way such that we can specify where to split (`rpartition`, I presume, splits the last string). Or maybe some way to concat the list given by `split`.

Comment: Also, I added a note. Even this method forces me to write a `+` concat line at the end, but shorter as I want to keep my whole string.

Answer (score 1):

You can try [rsplit](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.rsplit):

```
"centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21_2.0.jpg".rsplit("_", 1)
['centerOne_camera_2_2018-04-11_15:11:21', '2.0.jpg']
```